# LibreOffice and Windows Dark Mode - Menu not readable

Tags: libreoffice

since I have switched to dark mode in Windows 11 LibreOffice menues are shown like in the picture.

Cany anyone help me to change the look and feeld.

Regards,

Oliver[LibreOffice Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jGbl.png)

Tried to change the theme and view, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome! Do you really expect someone here to help you solve [**TDF#128287**](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=128287)? I assure you, this is not the right place. You can add your message in Bugzilla, this can speed up the solution of the problem for everyone